# Spring oauth2 authorization flow - preapproval in app

Tags: spring, api, oauth-2.0, authorization

we have a server to server communication that we wish to protect with oauth , but the authorization needs to be of a user. (cause the main server maintains a session and perform some validations of user permissions which are not spring roles checking ).

at first i thought of client_credencials but i needed to perform some mapping between the clientid and user. this  kind of requires a hidden login on server to have the user session initialized.
also this is not the recommended flow (as written in the spring ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter code)

so i think i want to try a different approach like authrization_code but i don't want any redirects here.i want something as simple as that.

1. user log in to our application (main server)
2. generate authorization request - like create API keys or something.
3. user is presented with authorization_code and state
4. user goes to the other server and put the code and state somewhere (don't care)
5. the other server use the code and state to be exchanged for token.

how can i achieve this ?
thanks

Shlomi

Comment: the standard flow would be: `1. user goes to other server 2. other server generates authorization request and redirects to main server 3. user logs in to main server 4. user is redirected back to other server with code+state 5. other server exchanges code for token; are you trying to avoid redirect 2. but not 4.?

Comment: in 4 there is no redirect, the user open the other server app and insert the details. the reason to avoid redirects is complicated , its an on premise product that works against a saas product which in saas users are authenticated by external provider, so redirects between 3 parties is more complicated for us to achieve. this why i thought everything can be done on the saas side app and the user will copy the details into the on-premise product.

Comment: still have no solid solution for this -even with JWT the question  remains - who is the user ? should we create it beforehand for the integration?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a JWT from your server to the remote server that identifiers the user and the remote server can use that as a "grant" to obtain an access token from your server. This is called JWT Authorization Grant. The specification (work in progress) is here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-12 but there are a number of implementations out there already. Below is an example JSON object that could be encoded to produce the JWT Claims Object for a JWT:

```
 {
  "iss":"https://jwt-idp.example.com",
  "sub":"mailto:mike@example.com",
  "aud":"https://jwt-rp.example.net",
  "nbf":1300815780,
  "exp":1300819380,
  "http://claims.example.com/member":true
 }
```

To present the JWT with the claims and header shown in the previous example as part of an access token request, for example, the client might make the following HTTPS request (with extra line breaks for display purposes only):

```
POST /token.oauth2 HTTP/1.1
Host: authz.example.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.
eyJpc3Mi[...omitted for brevity...].
J9l-ZhwP[...omitted for brevity...]
```

Of course the implementations on both sides needs to support this grant type, but it should be be too hard to add this to an existing OAuth 2.0 implementation since it reuses large parts of other grant types.

Comment: thanks Hans, actually i looked into this at google developer site and when i tried to create one - it downloaded a certificate to my computer which i then needed to do something with it :-). maybe i got the wrong impression because of google flow but it looks even worse than redirects.

Comment: after looking at this page from salesforce - its even more complicated than i suspected:-) https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm

Comment: You're not supposed to code this from scratch: use a JWT/JOSE library to create and sign it and all you have to do is POST it as shown in the sample.